# How can I change value of prop in react?

Tags: reactjs

How to change the value of props, how to setProps, suppose the value of this.props.contact.name is John, I want to change it to Johnny.

How can I do this?

For example:

```
changeValue(){
  this.props.contact.name='Johnny'
}
```

Comment: A component cannot update its own props unless they are arrays or objects (having a component update its own props even if possible is an anti-pattern), but can update its state and the props of its children.

Answer (score 7):

You would change the `prop` in the parent component, as that is what holds the value of the `prop` itself. This would force a re-render of any child components that use the specific `prop` being changed. If you want to intercept the `props` as they're sent, you can use the [lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest rather then change the props value you can pass the function into props and then change the parent component state so it will change the child component props like

your Parent Component should be

```
  class SendData extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {
      images: [
        'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
        'http://via.placeholder.com/350x151'
      ],
      currentImage: 0
    };
    this.fadeImage=this.fadeImage.bind(this);
  }
  fadeImage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({currentImage: (this.state.currentImage + 1) % this.state.images.length})
  }
  render()
  {

    return(
      <FadeImage images={this.state.images} currentImage={this.state.currentImage} fadeImage={this.fadeImage}/>
     )
  }
}
```

your Child Component should be like

```
    class FadeImage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
            <div className="image">
      <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="example"
        transitionEnterTimeout={300}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
        >
          <section>
            <button className="button" onClick={this.props.fadeImage.bind(this)}>Click!</button>
            <img src={this.props.images[this.props.currentImage]}/></section>
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Please check working example here [Demo](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KmW4JaxHgjS99eUSKN7)

Comment: why do you have `bind` on `this.props.fadeImage.bind(this)` in the child component? @Dhaval Patel

Answer (score 3):

Props are **immutable**, that means you can not change them!
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

If you want to save a new value build it as a state and use `this.setState(...)`
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html