# react: how to filter an array of objects in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `props` with following data

```
test1: abc
id: 1
myArray: Array(3)
0: {a:abc, b:cde, aid: 1}
1: {e:age, f:ade, aid: 2}
2: {t:are, h:had, aid: 1}
```

I want to filter props and update array to have only the values that match `id` and `aid`

So the props should look like below:

```
test1: abc
id: 1
myArray: Array(3)
0: {a:abc, b:cde, aid: 1}
2: {t:are, h:had, aid: 1}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: I was gonna post a filter implementation but there is one detail, props are inmutable... is that correct? you want to change the props of the current component?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) Array method

```js
let myArray = [{a:"abc", b:"cde", aid: 1},
               {e:"age", f:"ade", aid: 2},
               {t:"are", h:"had", aid: 1}]

const result = myArray.filter(item => item.aid === 1)

console.log(result)
```

But take in consideration that props are **immutable**.

If you wish to change this `prop` permanently you will have to [update it in the parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519475/how-can-i-change-value-of-prop-in-react).

Answer (score 1):

You will get the filtered data by using,

```
const filteredData = this.props.myArray.filter(item => item.aid === 1)
```

However props is only readable. You will have to eigther dispatch or update parent component to provide new/filtered data as props.

Comment: I am new to React. Could useState be used to update the state according the filtered list? Say, if I'm filtering 3 lists out of the prop variable, should I have 3 separate states? Thanks!

Comment: Found it! Filtering and creating new variables out of props should involve useStates that  are called upon useEffects.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Array.filter()`

```
// match both a AND aid
const result = myArray.filter(obj => (obj.a === test1 && obj.aid === id);
// match either a OR aid
const result = myArray.filter(obj => (obj.a === test1 || obj.aid === id);
```